Python websocket
I've been trying to get access to the websocket of this site through Python, but it needs to bypass CloudFlare, and now I've tried to make the bypass through cookies, but this didn't work.
I've tried doing it without the cookies, but that didn't work either.
import selenium.webdriver
import websocket
import base64
import os

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://bandit.camp/")
all_cookies=driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = {}
for cookie in all_cookies:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']

print('__cf_bm='+cookies_dict['__cf_bm'])
driver.quit()

def generate_websocket_key():
    key = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(16)).decode('utf-8')
    return key

ws_url = "wss://api.bandit.camp/"

headers = {
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': generate_websocket_key(),
    'Cookie': '__cf_bm='+cookies_dict['__cf_bm']
}

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(f"Received message: {message}")

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(f"Error: {error}")

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print(f"Closed connection with status code {close_status_code} and message {close_msg}")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(ws_url,
                            header=headers,
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_error=on_error,
                            on_close=on_close,
                            on_open=on_open)

ws.run_forever()

